# Where to add the like clause in php?

Tags: php, sql-like, where-clause

where can I put the like statement on this code? I would want to allow the user to search any documents that are similar to the entered text it would be document like '%$search%;

```
public function getDoc($param=''){
        if($this->User->PrincipalType!="All")$where['tbl_document.PrincipalType']=$this->User->PrincipalType;
        if(!isset($param['RecordID']) || $param['RecordID']==''){
            $where['tbl_document.Status !=']='Removed';
            $this->db->select('tbl_document.*,cr.FirstName,cr.MiddleName,cr.LastName,up.FirstName as UFName,up.MiddleName as UMName,up.LastName as ULName');
            $this->db->from('tbl_document');
            $this->db->join('tbl_user `cr`', 'tbl_document.CreatedBy = cr.ID','left');
            $this->db->join('tbl_user `up`', 'tbl_document.UpdatedBy = up.ID','left');
            if(isset($param['DocTrack']) && $param['DocTrack']!='')         $where['tbl_document.ID']=$param['DocTrack'];
            $this->db->where($where);
            if(isset($param['DocTrack']) && $param['DocTrack']!='')$this->db->or_where('tbl_document.Title',$param['DocTrack']);

            $this->db->order_by('DateCreated', 'desc');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $return=$query->result();
        }
```

Comment: What framework/ORM are you using? The way to do it will depend on that

Comment: Seems like you would add it to the `$where` array...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to search for `$param['DocTrack']` then you can use below two approaches for like query execution as below:

```
 1. $this->db->like('tbl_document.Title','%'.$param['DocTrack'].'%')
 2. $this->db->where("tbl_document.Title LIKE '%".$param['DocTrack']."%'");
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: What is `$this->db`? How do you know it has a `like()` method?

Comment: From OP's code, `where()` does not look to take a string argument.

Comment: It did not work. It did not show any search results.

Comment: after `$query = $this->db->get();`, please write `echo $this->db->last_query(); die;` it will show you the exact raw query. Post that here so I can check